# Android: Cursor doesn't return all videos saved in app folder in external storage

Tags: java, android, video

I'm currently developing video app and can save videos to app folder successfully.
But when I want to display app videos in recyclerview, it doesn't display all videos (as I debug app, the cursor doesn't return all videos, and when I restart device, it returns all videos, I have to restart device if new video is added in app folder to see all videos)

Here's source code.

```
public static List<MyVideo> getAppVideos(Context context) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN, MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION};
    String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID + " = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = { APP_VIDEO_BUCKET_ID };
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC");
    ArrayList<MyVideo> result = new ArrayList<MyVideo>(cursor.getCount());
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        final int dataColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
        final int dateColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN);
        final int durationColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION);
        do {
            final String data = cursor.getString(dataColumn);
            final String createdDate = cursor.getString(dateColumn);
            final String durationTime = cursor.getString(durationColumn);
            result.add(new MyVideo(data, DateUtils.convertToSeconds(durationTime), "^ " +  DateUtils.getDateFromMilliSeconds(Long.parseLong(createdDate), "MMM dd, yyyy")));

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return result;


}
```

Comment: i checked your ans.but can't know your problem...(:

Comment: sorry but what do you mean?, the cursor returns 0 count even there are 5 videos in app folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Actually it's the **Android** Nature.
When you add some New files to External Storage it will take sometime to Add it to Media Content Provider.Androdid System will automatically runs a mediascan in particular period.There is a workaround for that you need to trigger the Android System for a media scan

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(videoAdded)));
```

2.When you restart the device it will scan for the media and you will get all the videos

Comment: Thanks, I found solution from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
 I have to restart device if new video is added in app folder to see all videos
```

Yes. That is normal behavior. As after restart the MediaSotore will have indexed all mediafiles on your device. If you add a file the mediastore does not know aboutt that file.

So you have to tell the mediastore (with a few lines of code) that there is a new file to be indexed every time you created a new file.

Google for mediascanner and new file as code has been posted many times here.

Comment: Googled about mediascanner and have understanding of what that is, :) thanks.